# Atom invalid flag Java

Tags: java, atom-editor

I'm using a the Atom code editor and I want to print "`hello word`", but there is an error.

Here is my code:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ]args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
javac: invalid flag: /Users/student/Downloads/coding/test-1.Java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: tips: Rename the file to the same class name. Make the class public.

Comment: What command did you type in in order to execute?

Comment: Rename your file name as your class name and make it public.

Comment: Atom is not really a Java IDE. Have you considered using a Java IDE such as _Eclipse_ or _Intellij_ or _NetBeans_ or _JDeveloper_ ?

Comment: which class you are trying to compile. It is not the same class I believe Because the change you have done is `MyClass` and in your error it is showing `test-1.java`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error rename your file to use an all lowercase file extension

```
test-1.java
```

to adhere to Java standard make sure your file and class name are the same

```
MyClass.java
```